# Why Firebug pretends that my stylesheet is calling my xmlrpc?

Tags: php, wordpress

Firebug shows a request which causes a huge delay to
http://reboltutorial.com/wp-content/themes/minaflow/none

Details below but I don't understand why it says it comes from xmlrpc and the stylesheet:

```
Date Sun, 04 Apr 2010 16:10:02 GMT
Server Apache
X-Powered-By PHP/5.2.13
X-Pingback http://reboltutorial.com/xmlrpc.php
Expires Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma no-cache
Set-Cookie wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; path=/; domain=.reboltutorial.com
Last-Modified Sun, 04 Apr 2010 16:10:03 GMT
Vary Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding gzip
Keep-Alive timeout=2, max=94
Connection Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding chunked
Content-Type text/html; charset=UTF-8
Requêtemise en page impression

GET /wp-content/themes/minaflow/none HTTP/1.1
Host: reboltutorial.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; fr; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://reboltutorial.com/wp-content/themes/minaflow/style.css
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Please remove SESSION_ID and all cookies from post (it's quote easy for hacker to access to your site with that)

2) In CSS you have 3 times next code:

```
background: url(none);
```

That's why it goes to 404 error!

Comment: He probably means `background-image: none` instead.

Comment: whoa, simple mistake like that could slow down a site! *That's new to me*

Comment: well, the problem is also with 404 in his page. It shows full HTML page for 404 which takes time and process for server to render it...

Comment: Done won 2 seconds ! Now site is fast ! below 4 seconds :)

Comment: Problem is there is now an appearance css glitch on list