# How to correct this glitch

Tags: css

I removed

```
background: url(none);
```

in my stylesheet because of load performance [Why Firebug pretends that my stylesheet is calling my xmlrpc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577422/why-firebug-pretends-that-my-stylesheet-is-calling-my-xmlrpc)

The problem is that it now causes some glitch on css list.

Any idea how to fix this ?

Thanks.

Update: picture below

http://reboltutorial.com/wp-content/themes/minaflow/glitch.png

Tried to put background: none as suggested but didn't solve the problem/

```
ul.sidebar_list li ul li ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px!important;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: Going to have to be more specific about what glitches it's causing, sounds like you may have removed some CSS that you shouldn't have.

Comment: see picture above i just added.

Comment: And you did not read my answer correctly. I suggested to add `background-image:none` and not `background:none` .

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. But I just tried with background-image it doesn't work either so I restored the old stylesheet ... unless someone get another idea :)

Answer (score 3):

Referring to your other question I assume you mean the background image on your list items within the sidebar. You have to explicitly declare that you don't want a background image on the inner list items inside the list of widgets in your sidebar.

See line 370 of your styles.css and add `background-image:none;` as shown:

```
ul.sidebar_list li ul li {
    background-image:none;
}
```

Good luck with your blog!